# Amazon EC2 MySQL crashing issue because of less memory, how to sort it out?

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-ec2

I am new to Amazon EC2, recently I found mysql is not working properly, continuously crashing.

I think issue is less space or something..

Here is the some of the outputs:

*free -k
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1020536     254744     765792          0      54028      83748
-/+ buffers/cache:     116968     903568
Swap:        82628          0      82628*

*swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file    82628   0       -1*

I am not able to start the mysql.

Can someone please suggest me the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Check the InnoDB cache size in my.cnf file. If it is more than the size of your system's memory you found your problem. Try to reduce that and try to start MySQL.